# Using Encounter Power twice per round?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Can you use the same encounter power twice in one round if you use power jewel to recharge and then an action point to use it again?

I am looking to use Diabolic Strategm, power jewel, action point, diabloic strategm, brash assault to get an extra 10 (ME and 4 allies) attacks on the target...Looks like it should work...

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**

Unless a power explicitly says it can only be used once per round, then you can use it as many times as your actions and your ability to refresh the power and the power's trigger conditions (if any) permit. If it's a triggered power, it can only be used once per trigger.

Note that this does *not* work for Diabolic Stratagem: you can only take 1 opportunity action per turn, so even though 2 Diabolic Stratagems would arguably cause the creature to "provoke" twice when it makes its first attack, you and your allies are each only capable of making 1 opportunity attack against it during its turn.

Comment: yeah if you're going to use it twice, use it on two targets.